# React Material UI GridList row/column issue

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

I'm trying to display images into a GridList with Material UI. Unfortunately, it's producing a gap (red square) between some of the images as shown below:

[what the grid looks currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpIQ5.png)

and here is what my code looks like:

```
      <GridList  className="gridList" cols={3}>
        {this.state.images.map((tile, index) => (
          <GridListTile rows={index === 0 ? 2 : 1} cols={index === 0 ? 2 : 1}>
            <img src={tile.url} alt={tile.title} />
          </GridListTile>
        ))}
      </GridList>
```

If anybody can possibly guide me to the correct solution, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** Add the `spacing={0}` prop to your GridList.

**NL;PR:**  Your code should look like this:

```js
 <GridList  className="gridList" cols={3} spacing={0}>
```

You can play with other props [too](https://material-ui.com/api/grid-list/#gridlist-api).

Note: In Material 5, GridList has been renamed to ImageList.